# How to pause Sweave Compilation in Rstudio to check variables

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, sweave

I've inherited a sweave file from a different author. I'd like to pause it after it finishes running the R code to interrogate the variables and see the objects in the console before it goes to PDF generation.

Is there a way to do this Rstudio conveniently? Or even in emacs if I must?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging or checking `Sweave` documents, run the file through `Stangle`, e.g.

Stangle("a.rnw")

This produces a pure R-file, which you can debug separately. If the tangled files runs ok, but the `Sweave`'d does not, it is almost always due to some `\Sexpr{}` expression. These are difficult to locate, the error messages can be highly confusing.